# Unable to use tenant-specific endpoint when authenticating personal MS accounts using Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, azure-authentication

We would like our customers to be able to authenticate using either personal or work accounts. We have set up a seperate AD in Azure to which customers are invited which should grant them access to our application.

In the ASP.NET Core application `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{myTenantID}/v2.0` is used as authentication endpoint. A client id and secret from an application registered in the preview app registration through the portal is provided with the request. Authenticating our work accounts works smoothly, but when attempting to authenticate most personal accounts an error message is returned: `An error was encountered while handling the remote login. AADSTS50020: MSA guest token redemption attempt on v2 common endpoint.`

Should it not be possible to authenticate a MSA using a tenant-specific endpoint (only `/common`)?

Similar problem: [Azure AD B2B Authentication error for users with custom domains - AADSTS65005: Using application 'My Application' is currently not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51063547/azure-ad-b2b-authentication-error-for-users-with-custom-domains-aadsts65005-u)

Also, this comment points out that authenticating MSAs in multi-tenant apps will not work, however, ours should be sigle-tenant:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-roleclaims/issues/10#issuecomment-145125080

Comment: which option did you choose in preview , Accounts in any organizational directory and personal Microsoft accounts?

Comment: in this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app

Comment: are you using ADAL or MSAL library to authenticate?

Comment: You should be authenticating using https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0 endpoint

Comment: @AnassKartit "Accounts in any organizational directory and  personal MSA" for your first question. For your second question: I am using MSAL. And yes, part of my question was whether I must use the common endpoint or not. So the answer is in that case, yes, I have to use common.

Comment: yes you should use common, are you receiving an error with common?

Comment: We need to discuss whether what we have as of now is enough or not. I haven't tried common yet, but I'll have to come back to you if we figure we want to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use common endpoint if you are targeting both B2C and B2B using v2 endpoint for both work and personal emails to be able to call Azure AD protected endpoints.